# SQL query for this problem

Tags: mysql

I have one single table.

Table A has two columns

id, sample_id

an id will be associated with multiple sample_id..However both values i.e combined are unique

example,

```
id, sample_id
1, 10
1, 11
1, 12
2, 9
2, 10
2, 11
```

Now i want to update all the records of "1" to "2" provided it doesn't have a record in "2"

How to do it? Expected Result

```
id, sample_id
1, 10
1, 11
2, 12
2, 9
2, 10
2, 11
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.sample_id = t2.sample_id AND t2.id = 2
SET t1.id = 2
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d8228f078412be03fcfa5f2cd6c00e2)

Comment: Is it possible to delete and update in a single statement....I want to delete the remaining rows of "1" which is not required any more...

Comment: @OdataDev No, this two actions cannot be mixed in one SQL statement.

Comment: ok..Thank you..i have one more problem..I am creating now..Please advise with your comments

Comment: akina, i have posted the new question. Please kindly help me and do the needful